# how write insert string in command line

Tags: c#, batch-file, dos

Does anyone knows how the right way to write a  query string that will be taken as parameter on the command line?  How should it be formated?

Comment: I would ask for an example of what you want, but I think that's what you're asking us for. Can you try to explain, with context, what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Has it something to do with trapping the command line parameter(including query string?)

Comment: Do you mean `SQL INSERT statement`? You really need to provide more details about what you're asking.

Comment: Are you asking about the QueryString parameters on a URL? The variable=value pairs that follow the question mark?

Answer (score 4):

I'm a little unsure if I'm interpreting what you're asking correctly.  But I assume you mean passing a command-line argument to a batch file.  If this is wrong, let me know and I'll delete it.  (But if I'm assuming right, this is really off-topic as it's not really a programming issue.)

By default batch files assume that each space is a dlimiter for another parameter so

```
C:>Start.exe my command parameter
```

launches the start.exe program with three parameters: "my", "command", and 
parameter".

If I assume correctly, you're asking how to get these to be ONE parameter.

In which case, enclose the parameter in quotes.

```
C:>Start.exe "my command parameter"
```

will be read as one command argument "my command parameter"

```
C:>Start.exe "my command" parameter
```

will be read as two arguments - "my command" and "parameter"  etc.

Comment: If I'm assuming wrong, please clarify by editing your question.  Don't comment on this answer because once I delete it, your comment willl be lost.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Process** in **System.Diagnostics**

Example:

```
        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
        process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe";
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c \"ping 192.168.0.15\"";
        process.Start();
```

Comment: I'm almost sure that you answered what he was getting at.  Nice guess.  +1.